# Ways of editing Postgis tables from remote desktops (WFS?)

Tags: postgis, mapserver, mapfile

I've got like 500 postgis tables and i would like to serve then as WMS and especially as WFS to be able to edit that info. To do so i read that the easiest way is Mapserver + TinyOWS. Mapserver works with .map files so i need to generate the map files form postgis tables.

I am also testing geoserver. But i am getting a Provider errors: empty response whenever I try to edit the layer.

Which would be the easiest way to make a fully working WMS + WFS service?

Regards,

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by a mapfile. What format, for where?

Comment: MapServer is configured with mapfiles and those who know enough for answering know what they are. But I do not understand what you mean by "generating a mapfile from postgis table". Do you wish a have a system that builds automatically a mapfile that is publishing some table from PostGIS through WMS?

Comment: @user30184. OK, fair enough, I guess I should have read the tags, there wasn't much clue in the actual question.

Comment: I read the title.

Comment: @user30184. Anyway, I am a GeoServer person, so I will shut up and go away now. I still think the question could do with some work.

Comment: i've got like 500 postgis tables and i would like to serve then as WMS and especially as WFS. To do so i read that the easiest way is Mapserver + TinyOWS. Mapserver works with .map files so i need to generate the map files form postgis tables

Comment: You would be better to edit the question with this information.

Comment: edited on 26.12.2014